# Resolution of the ideal of the Abel-Jacobi image of a curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, jacobians

Let $C$ be a complex curve of genus $g\ge 2$ and let $a\colon C\to J(C)$ be the Abel-Jacobi map. Is there a finite resolution of the ideal $\mathcal I_{a(C)}$ whose terms are sums  line bundles of the form  $\mathcal O_{J(C)}(m \Theta)$?

I think I remember seeing something of this type years ago, but I haven't been able to find anything related  on the web. Maybe I just imagined it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true, as soon as   $g\geq 3$. Taking Chern classes this would imply that $c_{g-1}(\mathcal{O}_{a(C)})$ is an integral multiple of $\ \Theta ^{g-1}$ in $\ H^{2g-2}(JC,\mathbb{Z})$. But $c_{g-1}(\mathcal{O}_{a(C)})=(-1)^{g}(g-2)![a(C)]=(-1)^g\frac{\Theta ^{g-1}}{g-1}\ $, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you please  explain how one computes the coefficient $(-1)^g(g-2)!$ in the formula?

Comment: For a closed irreducible subvariety $Z$ of codimension $p$ in a smooth projective variety $X$, one has $c_p(\mathcal{O}_Z)=(-1)^{p-1}(p-1)![Z]$ in $H^{2p}(X,\mathbb{Z})$  (even actually in the Chow ring). See for instance Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, Example 15.3.1.